# Cannot find user certificates in Windows registry

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, certificate

I am not an advanced Windows user, I was just trying to understand where Windows 10 is storing user certificates.

I have issued this command within powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\myself> ls Cert:\CurrentUser\My\

   PSParentPath: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::CurrentUser\My

Thumbprint                                Subject
----------                                -------
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  CN......
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  CN......
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  CN......
```

As a confirmation, by opening `certmgr` I can see the certificates in it

[image: certmgr screenshot]

However when I am browsing the registry I cannot see any certificates in it:

```
PS C:\Users\Myself> ls 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\*'
PS C:\Users\Myself>
```

I have also opened the `regedit` tool and the folder looks empty.

Searching the thumbprint in the whole registry using regedit ends up in zero result.

Why is that ? Am I doing something wrong ? Could it be a privilege problem or the user certificates are maybe just located somewhere else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public and private keys are not stored in the same place.
Public certificates are stored in the registry, but their
associated private keys are stored in the file system.

My public keys are in the registry at:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates`.

I find my private keys on the disk at:
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates`

The PowerShell command `ls Cert:\CurrentUser\My\`
returns installed certificates with public keys.

For more information see the article
[System Store Locations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/system-store-locations).

Comment: What's the format of the file in the AppData/Roaming directory ? .pfx, .pem .... ? If I am using certutil I can see what's in it, while with openssl I cannot inspect it, I am instead getting various error.

Comment: I don't know the format, but it seems to be mixed and different for the various stores. You can find a very detailed treaty of the subject in the article [Managing Certs with Windows Certificate Manager and PowerShell](https://adamtheautomator.com/windows-certificate-manager/).